# The meaning of the term - Resource Acquisition Is Initialization

Tags: c++, oop, terminology, raii

I know what RAII does. It is all about preventing memory leaks etc. when/if a code throws an exception.

Now, I wish to understand the meaning of that *smart* term.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acquisition

Acquisition means acquiring something.

So, when we say that ***resource acquiring is initialization***, what does that  mean?
I am just talking about the meaning of the term here, not about the concept in general.

Comment: Do a search on this site.  Tons of info.

Comment: @AnonMail already done it. They explain the concept, not the meaning of this "term"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please help us non-C++ developers understand what RAII is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712639/please-help-us-non-c-developers-understand-what-raii-is)

Comment: Many questions about this. Another one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095185/why-is-raii-so-named

Comment: @Laurent that answer hasn't received any votes.

Comment: @Anisha: I don't think that means it's wrong. The question was closed off-topic, so it's unlikely that many people looked at it. I guess it was closed by people who have little curiosity about the meanings of words, or at least who think that understanding programming terminology is not a programming problem. They may have a point.

Comment: @Anisha, the first link as plenty of up-voted answers, from 2 upvotes to 75, so I don't think another question is needed.

Comment: @SteveJessop ` I don't think that means it's wrong. ` Nor did I say that it is wrong. I just meant that I don't know much about this question so I am not sure that I should be taking his words for granted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has been said before (possibly by Scott Meyers, I can't remember), that RAII should be called "Destruction is resource release", or words to that effect.

What "resource acquisition is initialization" literally means is that when an object is constructed (initialized), it acquires some resource (such as a memory allocation or a lock). In other words, it says you should only ever *acquire* a resource, by *initializing* some object whose destructor will release it.

This is important to stress because it's a departure from C coding style, where you acquire resources by whatever means a particular API provides (for example `malloc()`, `accept()`, or `pthread_mutex_lock()`), and release them by explicitly calling the corresponding function (for example `free()`, `close()`, `pthread_mutex_unlock()`). The presence of exceptions in C++ makes this approach fairly unworkable. Even in C it results in some tedious code that every use of the API has to write out, and every user has to ensure that control always passes through that code after they're finished using the resource.

But the important part of the pattern is that when the object is destroyed, it releases that resource. It doesn't actually matter whether you acquire the resource by initializing the object, or by doing something else with the object after it has been initialized. And people will still refer to an object as a "RAII object" when there are operations other than initialization that generate the resource(s) managed by the RAII object.

So, don't worry too much about the "acquisition is initialization" in "RAII", because anyway it's slightly misleading.

Comment: The problem is that `int * p = malloc(1000);` is also initialization of an (integer) object, but it's not the kind of initialization we mean in the context of RAII.

Comment: @Fred: Indeed. `int*` is not a RAII type because it doesn't do cleanup. So it's not what RAII means, even though it is what RAII literally says.

Answer (score 0):

Acquisition is a generic term, but it refers always to an operation that allocates some resource - e.g. a file handle, a database connection, a mutex, ... - specifically to your code, which "owns" it, and thus must be released when it's not needed to avoid leaking resources.

The important concept with RAII is that the resource lifetime is bound to the lifetime of the owner object, because the acquisition coincides with the initialization (=creation of the object), and the release with its destruction (which is guaranteed).